# Why a random minimum spanning tree is not an uniform spanning tree?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, random

A spanning tree chosen randomly from among all the spanning trees with equal probability is called a *uniform spanning tree*.

A model for generating spanning trees randomly but not uniformly is the *random minimum spanning tree*. In this model, the edges of the graph are assigned random weights and then the minimum spanning tree of the weighted graph is constructed [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree#Randomization).

Why a *random minimum spanning tree* is not an *uniform spanning tree* ?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2109978/14578, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/69171/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Random minimum spanning tree is a spanning tree that was obtained via Kruskal's algorithm starting with a random permutation. Take a graph that is a square with one diagonal (4 vertices, 5 edges). There are 8 spanning trees (4 that include the diagonal, and 4 that don't), each should be picked with probability $1/8$. However, that is no so for random minimum spanning tree. Consider the following 5 cases (each happens with equal probability):

1. The diagonal is first. - The diagonal edge is certainly picked.
2. The diagonal is second. - The diagonal edge is certainly picked.
3. The diagonal is third. - First edge is irrelevant, 3 cases for the second edge:

   - same side - no diagonal.
   - other side, adjacent - with diagonal.
   - other side, not adjacent - with diagonal.
4. The diagonal is fourth. - The first 3 edges form a spanning tree, no diagonal.
5. The diagonal is fifth. - Same as above, no diagonal.

All in all, we get the following distribution, as you can see, the split is not equal:

- no diagonal: $\frac{2}{5} + \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{3} = \frac{7}{15}$.
- diagonal: $\frac{2}{5} + \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{8}{15}$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$